# Quartz @DisallowConcurrentExecution not working

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Hi i have two jobs instances in quartz that i want to not run in parallel, i simplified the code in the example below to show what is not in line with my expectations.

```
public class QuartzTest {

public static void main( String[] args ) throws SchedulerException {
SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
scheduler.start();

JobDetail job1 = newJob( TestJob.class ).withIdentity( "job1", "group1" ).build();
CronTrigger trigger1 = newTrigger().withIdentity( "trigger1", "group1" ).startAt( new Date() ).withSchedule( cronSchedule( getCronExpression( 1 ) ) ).build();
scheduler.scheduleJob( job1, trigger1 );

JobDetail job2 = newJob( TestJob.class ).withIdentity( "job2", "group1" ).build();
CronTrigger trigger2 = newTrigger().withIdentity( "trigger2", "group1" ).startAt( new Date() ).withSchedule( cronSchedule( getCronExpression( 1 ) ) ).build();
scheduler.scheduleJob( job2, trigger2 );

for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    System.out.println( trigger1.getNextFireTime() );
    System.out.println( trigger2.getNextFireTime() );
    try {
    Thread.sleep( 1 * 60 * 1000 );
    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

private static String getCronExpression( int interval ) {
return "0 */" + interval + " * * * ?";

}

}
```

This is the job class

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class TestJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute( JobExecutionContext context ) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println( "Job started" );
    System.out.println( "Job sleeping 30s..." );
    try {
        Thread.sleep( 30 * 1000 );
    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println( "Job finished." );
    }

}
```

So here i am scheduling two jobs to run each minute (in the real case one is running every minute the other every 5) and this is the output i am getting:

```
Job started
Job sleeping 30s...
Job started
Job sleeping 30s...
Job finished.
Job finished.
```

So both job are running in parallel, because a sequential sequence where job1 waits for job2 to complete before running would give me this sequence

```
Job started
Job sleeping 30s...
Job finished.
Job started
Job sleeping 30s...
Job finished.
```

So why is this not happening ?

Answer (score 3):

From docs:

@DisallowConcurrentExecution:

An annotation that marks a Job class as one that must not have multiple instances executed concurrently (where instance is based-upon a JobDetail definition - or in other words based upon a JobKey).

JobKey is composed of both a name and group

In your example the name is not the same, so this is two different jobs.

DisallowConcurrentExecution is ensuring that job1#thread1 is completed before you trigger another job1#thread2.